# String includes just valid chars?

Tags: c++, string

I'd like to valid a string to check if the string just includes valid characters or not using C++.

> Valid characters should be given to the `function` like as charset of valid characters: **"abc123"**.

A string that just includes the characters given in the charset above should `return true` while a string that also includes other characters then given should `return false`. Obviously a easy task :)

---

--> using charset `abc123`:

```
string myString_1 = "bbbac1" // should get true 
string myString_2 = "bbbac132aacc" // should get true 

string myString_3 = "xxxxxx" // should get false
string myString_4 = "bbbac12533cc" // should get false
```

How can I implement a call like this in C++?

**Note**: I though about using something like the code below but I'm pretty sure theres a way better solution.

```
string charset = "abc123";
string myString = "bbbac1";

for (int i=0; i<charset.length(); i++) {
  std::replace( myString.begin(), myString.end(), charset[i], '');
}
bool isValid = (myString.length() == 0);
```

Comment: Just a typo, calm down guys. I've already removed the wrong tag `:)`

Comment: In C `strcspn` will do it.

Comment: As for the validation, perhaps using [`std::all_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of) with a suitable predicate (function, lambda, etc.)?

Comment: [`find_first_not_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find_first_not_of)

Comment: Would you mind to share 2 lines of code implementing `find_first_not_of` because it seems to be a working solution to me?   @IgorTandetnik

Comment: We leave writing those two lines as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Haha no problem. Yes, I would still refrain from the word "exercise". I have already written the code for this in the last 2 minutes. I thought you would like to post an answer matching the comment to get the checkmark. If not - also ok you already helped me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AS igor-tandetnik pointed in comments this is a job for [`std::find_first_not_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find_first_not_of):

```
auto validate(const std::string& str, const std::string& charset) -> bool
{
    return str.find_first_not_of(charset) == std::string::npos;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own check function:

```
bool checkstring(std::string &checkstring, std::string &legalchars) {
    for (char c : checkstring) {
        // resetting the bool
        bool isLegal = false;
        for (char d : legalchars) {
            // comparing the chars
            if (c == d) { isLegal = true; }
        }
        // if a non-legal char was found, return false
        if (!isLegal) { return false; }
    }
    // if no non-legal character was found, return true
    return true;
}
```

Although there might be a better alternative using the standard libraries, especially if you need to compare very long strings with a large set of legal characters.